# Test if plotly plot is empty

Tags: python, testing, plotly, is-empty

I want to build a generalisable function, to test if a plotly plot is empty or not.

Context: I recieve the plot data from some API. I want to test if it is empty or not. I have no access to the input dataframes, and I want to automate the tests such that I don't have to plot the graph, look at it, then conclude it's either empty, or not-empty.

Here is what I've have so far;

```
def check_plot_data_empty(plot_data):
    if 'data' in plot_data:
        for trace in plot_data['data']:
            data_keys = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'values', 'text', 'marker']
            for key in data_keys:
                if key in trace:
                    if key == 'marker':
                        if 'size' in trace['marker'] and len(trace['marker']['size']) > 0:
                            return False
                        if 'color' in trace['marker'] and len(trace['marker']['color']) > 0:
                            return False
                    else:
                        if isinstance(trace[key], list) and len(trace[key]) > 0:
                            return False
                        if key == 'text' and isinstance(trace[key], str) and trace[key].strip():
                            return False
    return True
```

This works pretty well for the 5-6 examples I've run. However, I need a more robust way to test if this will work for all types of plotly plots. Are there plotly testing frameworks, or other approaches I can take to fully test this function.

And I would welcome any counter-examples that shows this does not work, with the approach used to come up with it, which will help me test further.

Thanks!

Comment: If I run print(fig.data), I can check whether the data for the x- and y-axes that make up the graph exist. As a way to draw a large number of graphs, subplots cannot be supported because the composition of the subplots is determined first.

Comment: Yh, so this is using the fig.data. The problem is you won't always have a x and y axis with some of the more exotic plotly plots

Comment: as you mentioned, there are some more obscure plotly figures that have data_keys you haven't listed. for example, `Scatterpolar` plots populate the keys `r` and `theta`. also are you only reading in `plotly.express` or `plotly.graph_objects` figures?

Comment: I'm aiming for all of plotly. So including graph_obj

Comment: @GooJ in that case, you probably have some more cases to account for since `plotly.express` and `plotly.graph_objects` are structured slightly differently. if i have time, i'll see if i can write up an answer that extends the use case of what you have so far